# zabbix regex to trigger for wrong data type

Tags: zabbix

I have an item of type float, but sometimes a string is received in case of error instead of a number. How can I make a trigger regexp to fire in this case?

I have no idea now to check for "wrong data type".

Actually this is by design and what I'm trying to do is this: if the data gathering fails, I send an error message in order to see it on zabbix end.

I tried with nodata(0), but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

In you case zabbix will not store the "wrong" value for the item. And if you don't care what the string is then you can just setup a trigger for "nodata" for the period of your interval. Look in the [triggers manual](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/config/triggers) and search for the "nodata".

Edit: scratch that, didn't read the whole question ....

Edit2: if you are certain that this is not working by design and not because your trigger interval misses the data interval, then you can try to catch the unsupported status. There is an [open request](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-1003) for the functionality, but you can setup a side script similar to [this](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showpost.php?p=85153&postcount=7). Or you can wrap the monitored item on the node into a UserParameter script that reads the value and prints -1 or something if it is not a number. Then proceed with a normal numeric trigger.